# Unable to send emails to web mail servers from local server using Java Mail

Tags: java, apache, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send emails from Java Mail API. Currently I have installed `Apache James` as a testing mail server of my own. I have few email account users in James, they are "red", "green" and "blue".

Now, please have a look at the below code.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */

import java.util.*;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  
import javax.activation.*;  

public class Mail {

     public static void main(String [] args){  
      String host="localhost";  
  final String user="red@localhost";//change accordingly  
  final String password="red";//change accordingly  

  String to="abc@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
  //String to= "blue@localhost";

   //Get the session object  
   Properties props = new Properties();  
   props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
      }  
    });  

   //Compose the message  
    try {  
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
     message.setSubject("Test Mail From Localhost");  
     message.setText("Soetimes, it didnt work..");  

    //send the message  
     Transport.send(message);  

     System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  

     } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
 }  


}
```

There is a problem in this code. That is if I send the mail to a local email like blue@localhost, the mail will be sent. If I send it to a web based one like "Gmail", it do not go. However in both cases, I get the message `message sent successfully....

what is happening here?

Comment: It could either be a technical issue (e.g. mail server not configured to send to external addresses) or a spam filtering issue (e.g. Gmail has no authentication for your server so it puts the mail in the spam folder). Can you check the spam folder on the Gmail box?

Comment: @RealSkeptic: no spams. i cant send to any external email address not only gmail.;

Comment: So you'll need to look in the log file of your SMTP server.